# App launches again

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am not sure why this is happening, but i guess an suggestion will help me.

i have 4 view controllers.Whenever i exit from the app(app goes to background) and i open the app again, my app opens, as it is launched again, instead it should open the viewcontroller, from where i closed the app.

PS: i am not closing the app completely, i m just taping on home button, app goes to background.

I havn't wrote anything on appdelegate,which make this happening. Any suggestions?

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer, i checked the plist and  i had

> Application does not run in background : YES

I changed it to NO and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

According to me there are two scenarios when your app gets "relaunch" everytime

-->**If you app is crashing while pressing to home button on iphone**.
check if your app is performing any operation while going to inactive mode. For that check your `applicationWillResignActive` method.

-->**If you have set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` flag in your `.plist` file**.
This will cause the app not to go into the background when the user switches to another app.

If you still don't get what the problem is then I suggest you to add the exception handler in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method like this

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    // The rest if you code  ....
}

void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    // You code here, you app will already be unload so you can only see what went wrong.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting an exception when the application goes to the background, so it is killed instead. Maybe some wrong deallocation?

Connect your device to your debugger and watch what is happening when your app goes to the background. You should see the problem very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Few reasons for this to occur.

The application may be crashing as it is being backgrounded, maybe you are running some code on application will enter background in the app delegate which is causing a crash.

Comment: no,this cant be happeing, bcoz from all 4 controllers,app cant be crash.

Comment: and also, i have nothing to perform on background.so hvnt wrote any code.

Comment: Add a general exception breakpoint to your app in xcode.  You can look up how to do this if you don't know how.  Run the application from xcode onto a device live and connected, don't just put the app on the phone, make sure it is running through xcode.  Background the application on the device and see If it hits that exception breakpoint anywhere or spits out any messages in the debugger.  Also, make sure you are running on iOS4 and iPhone 3GS and above since older devices / iOS do not support backgrounding of apps.

Comment: I did the steps. i put a breakpoint at - (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated and this is called,when i tapped on home button. but nothing exceptional

Comment: Not to a line of code as you did, follow this small tutorial to add one: http://www.tekritisoftware.com/exception-breakpoint-xcode4.2-iphone-development